# Topic hierarchy in GCP pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm looking to implement a topic hierarchy pattern, whereby subscribers can subscribe to topics and receive multiple message types without the need for filtering.

For instance the following topics:

`customer.delete`
`customer.create`
`customer.update`

Could be subscribed to by individual services, however, if I subscribe to `customer` in another service, this receives all events from the customer hierarchy - `customer.delete`, `customer.create`, `customer.update`.

I would prefer to avoid filtering where possible. Is this pattern supported?

I can't find any details in the docs for this.

Cheers.

Comment: May I know the programming language that you are using for this one?

Comment: Hi, I am using Python. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notion of topic hierarchy in Cloud Pub/Sub. Although you say you want to avoid it, the best way to accomplish this would be through filtering where there is a single topic, `customer` and then an attribute to distinguish `delete`, `create`, and `update`. Subscriptions would be created with [filters](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscription-message-filter) that select only the desired event types.

Alternatively, you could have separate topics for each event type. If a subscriber only wants a single event type, it need only have a subscription for that particular topic. If it wants to process events for multiple event types, it would need a subscription to each topic it was interested in. For pull subscriptions, this would likely mean instantiating a subscriber instance for each subscription. If using push subscriptions, then the subscriber could sit behind a single endpoint that is reused across its subscriptions so the subscribe itself wouldn't have to know the list of subscriptions for which it needs to request messages.

Comment: Thanks for the clear response, much appreciated.